# Symfony2 - get array from SQL

Tags: arrays, symfony

Before to use Symfony I wrote my code in PHP. This was my code :

```
$query_nb_cat = "SELECT titre_categorie_nv1, COUNT(*) 
    FROM Tutoriels 
    INNER JOIN Groupe_de_categories 
    ON Tutoriels.id_groupe_categorie = Groupe_de_categories.id_groupe_categorie 
    WHERE tutoriel_controle='non' 
    GROUP BY titre_categorie_nv1";

$nb_cat = mysqli_query($BDD_connect, $query_nb_cat)or die(log_mysql($query_nb_cat));
    $row_nb_cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nb_cat);
do {
    $tableau_nb_cat[]=array(
        'titre_cat_nv1'=>$row_nb_cat['titre_categorie_nv1'],
        'compte_cat_nv1'=>$row_nb_cat['COUNT(*)'],
    );
} while ($row_nb_cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nb_cat));

$val_cat=array(
    'valeur_retour'=>$tableau_nb_cat
);
```

The response was like that (in an array) :

```
'Arts & Loisirs'  => '18' 
'Cuisine' =>  '55' 
'Informatique'=> '9'
```

Now with Symfony2 my query is like that:

```
$result = $em->createQuery("SELECT b.titreCategorieNv1, COUNT(b.titreCategorieNv1) 
                FROM Video2LearnBddBundle:Tutoriels p
                INNER JOIN p.idGroupeCategorie a
                INNER JOIN a.titreCategorieNv1 b
                WHERE p.tutorielControle='non'
                GROUP BY b.titreCategorieNv1")
                ->getResult();
```

The Dump result is like that :

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'titreCategorieNv1' => string 'Arts & Loisirs' (length=14)
      1 => string '18' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'titreCategorieNv1' => string 'Cuisine' (length=7)
      1 => string '55' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'titreCategorieNv1' => string 'Informatique' (length=12)
      1 => string '9' (length=1)
```

How can I have in return a response like that (the same like in my PHP code) ??:

```
  'Arts & Loisirs'  => '18' 
  'Cuisine' =>  '55' 
  'Informatique'=> '9'
```

Thank you

Comment: What you need is to create a loop for the results to generate the proper output you need (you cannot do it with DQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the last function:

```
$em->createQuery('YOUR SQL QUERY')->getArrayResult()
```

EDIT:

Sorry, checked again your code, but I don't see, how could your old code produce that output, cause in the do while, you are creating a new array with array element and 2 separate keys. There is no direct hydrate mode for that, you have to run a foreach for example.

Comment: The dump result is exactly the same :(